# javascript open url in a frame on the same page

Tags: javascript, html

The following simple code open a webpage with an Amazon phone softphone, I would like to also open a URL on the same page - to the right of the softphone.  I cant figure it out.  Thank you kindly for your help.  This line opens the URL in a new tab, but I want it in the same window to the right of the softphone: window.open(screenpopURL) all of the whitespace in the attached image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Call Center</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
        <script src="amazon-connect.min.js"></script> 
        <style>
            *, body {
                margin: 0;
                padding:0
            }
            iframe {
                border: 0px
            }
            #containerDiv {
                float: left;
                width: 320px;
                height: 465px
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="containerDiv"></div>
        <script>
            connect.core.initCCP(containerDiv, {
                ccpUrl:"https://XXXX.awsapps.com/connect/ccp-v2/softphone",
                loginPopup: true,
                softphone: {
                    allowFramedSoftphone: true
                 }
            });
            connect.contact(function(contact) {
                contact.onConnecting(function(contact) {
                    var attributeMap = contact.getAttributes();
                    var baseURL = attributeMap.screenPopURL.value;
                    var searchString = attributeMap.screenPopValue.value;
                    var screenpopURL = baseURL + searchString + ".html";
                    window.open(screenpopURL)            

                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: go for i frames

Comment: Hi!  I dont know how to split the javascript into two iframes?

Comment: its just a url right?? if so then embed it in an iframe then it will show the url content in the same page

Comment: for amazon softphone i am not sure about the syntax .. but ideally this is the way we use in html

Comment: Maybe you can clarify a bit more what you wanna achieve. You can use iframes

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV I think you are correct, I just cant figure out the syntax to put window.open(screenpopURL) into an iframe url right

Comment: @Grumpy this action window.open(screenpopURL) I am trying to get to display to the right of softphone, currently it pops open the URL into a new tab. I would like to to be on the same page displayed to the right of the softphone. I hope that makes sense, thank you so much!!

Comment: Aha, ok, dont use window.open, it will always open a new tab or window, you should use <iframe src=screenpopURL></iframe> or <iframe id="containerDivx"></iframe>

Comment: awesome thank you, when I changed it to <iframe src=screenpopURL></iframe>  the page doesnt load its just a white screen now.

Comment: changed it:  and it doesnt load now
            connect.contact(function(contact) {
                contact.onConnecting(function(contact) {
                    var attributeMap = contact.getAttributes();
                    var baseURL = attributeMap.screenPopURL.value;
                    var searchString = attributeMap.screenPopValue.value;
                    var screenpopURL = baseURL + searchString + ".html";
                    <iframe src=screenpopURL></iframe>